# GridView Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

Is there any event to let us know that we almost reach the last data in gridview?
I have a lot of data in my server, i want to load the data every 100 data, so if the user keep scrolling until the end of 100th data, i want to load another 100 data and put it in my gridview.

or is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to check the position in the getView method of the Adapter, and load data if the position is somewhere near the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (customAdapter.getCount() > 100) {
            if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                // add next pack 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
});
```